# Can't do apt-get upgrade due to "files list file for package 'linux-headers-5.3.0-51' contains empty filename"

Tags: boot, apt

My Ubuntu 18.04 is stuck at `Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service`. So, I thought upgrading to 20.04 might fix this. But `sudo apt-get upgrade` is throwing

```
files list file for package 'linux-headers-5.3.0-51' contains empty filename
```

To resolve this, I tried the following command without success:

```
sudo apt clean && sudo apt install linux-headers-5.3.0-51 --reinstall
```

What shall I do now? :)

**Update (2020/11/28):**

Upgrading to `20.04` resolved the `Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service` issue!

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall the package and re-install it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to manually remove the problematic file list by

```
sudo rm  /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-headers-5.3.0-51.list
```

and then reinstall package as usual

```
sudo apt install linux-headers-5.3.0-51 --reinstall
```

Comment: Thanks! it worked. But didn't resolve my original issue :P